# I'm making blog page in react using react router and firebase firestore , and i want get single post detail by id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

Hello everyone I'm making sort of blog page and have problem with retrieving data for single item from database  I searched solution for this problem and I just can't find it. In this project I use firestore and react router. This is my Home function (Home page), where i retrive items from database

```
function Home({isAuth}) {
  const[articlesList, setArticleList] = useState([])
  const articleCollectionRef = collection(db, 'articles')

  const deleteArticle = async (id) => {
      const articleDoc = doc(db, "articles", id)
      await deleteDoc(articleDoc)
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
      const getArticles = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(articleCollectionRef)
      setArticleList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})))
    }
      getArticles()
    },[deleteArticle])

  
 
  return <Grid container direction="row-reverse" justifyContent="space-evenly" alignItems="center" marginTop={2} >
    {articlesList.map((article) => {
      return(
          <Grid item alignItems="center" margin={1}>
            <Link to={`articles/${article.id}`} articlesList={articlesList} ><PostCard isAuth={isAuth} article={article} deleteArticle={deleteArticle}/></Link>
          </Grid>
    )})}
  </Grid>
}

export default Home;
```

And here is my single article component where i get item id with useParams but i dont know how to get item based on that id

```
const SingleArticle = () => {
  
  const { id } = useParams()

  return (
    <>
      < h5>Post with id: { id }</h5>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is it the same data you already fetched and stored in `articlesList` state in the `Home` component? What does `react-router` have to do with your question/issue? How are these two components rendered in relation to each other and any router and routes? Can you add all relevant code to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes it is the same data, I just don't know how to access data it in singleArticle component.

Comment: You've several options. You can [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor and pass down as props. You can abstract the lifting of state into a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) (*or Redux, etc...*). You could send in route state via the `Link` from the `Home` component to the `SingleArticle` component. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, I lifted the state up and passed state as props, and it worked.